# Status of anonymous binding with wso2 Identity Service and LDAP

Tags: ldap, wso2-identity-server

We are evaluating the use of wso2 with ldap.  I see no current mention of anonymous binding being available.  What is the current status of using anonymous bind?  If it is available, how is it configured?

TIA
Karen Lahey

Answer (score 0):

I guess,  anonymous binding is not available with WSO2 Identity Server.  It code, it has been coded as "simple".  By default, there is no way to configure it.  However,  reason for that Identity Server provides a user management functions with application level authorization mechanism. There is no worth, if we do not have any security between LDAP and server. However,  you can change it by extending current LDAP based implementation. You have freedom to plug your implementation for that.

environment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");

Comment: Also is there any reason for anonymous binding? It is great, if you could explain bit...

Answer (score 0):

With the new version of WSO2 Identity Server

you can make wso2is-5.6.0\repository\conf\user-mgt.xml

use

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager">
    <Property name="AnonymousBind">true</Property>
```